# tikz, draw line made up of + symbols

Tags: tikz-styles, draw

is it possible to use the command draw to generate a sequence of + symbols in line?

The output should be the same of a dotted line where the dots are replaced with + symbols (i.e.  + + + + + + + + + +). I tried to use it as a marker but did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I adapted the example in the tikz manual (48.5: Arbitrary Markings):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = {
            markings,
            mark = 
                between positions 0 and 1 step 5mm % adjust step size here
                with
                {
                    % adjust size of plus signs here
                    \draw (0pt, 2pt) -- (0pt, -2pt);
                    \draw (-2pt, 0pt) -- (2pt, 0pt);
                }
            }
        ]
        \path[decorate] (0, 0) -- (2, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With this, you get

[image]

You can adjust the step to get closer or more widely spaced plus signs.

As pointed out in the comments, the two drawing commands can be replaced by a simple `\node{+};`, which could be simpler.

Comment: Many thanks, I will employ this solution (y)

Comment: You can replace the code of your`with` by a simple `with {\node{+};}`

Comment: @JLDiaz you are right, thanks for the hint.