# How to Place a Node Relatively to a Decoration Path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path, tikz-decorations

I woud like to place a node below a `decoration` path (i.e. at something like "`myDecoratePath.south`") composed of a series of arrows: [image]

In order to obtain something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do it with the following Minimal Non Working Example (inspired from [pschulz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350347/262081))?

```
\documentclass[tikz,drop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{arrow/.pic={
    \draw[-latex,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);%
}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = {%
            markings,%
            mark =%
                between positions 0 and 1 step 5mm % adjust step size here
                with {%
                     {\pic {arrow};},
                      postaction={decorate}}%
            }%
        ]%
        \path[decorate] (0, 0) -- (2, 0);%
        % Here the node I would like to place at something like 'myDecoratePath.south'
        % \node (n1)  [draw, text width=3em, minimum height=2em]   {node 1};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your node right *inside* your path and adjust the positioning.

[image: node relative to a path]

```
\documentclass[tikz,drop,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, positioning}

\tikzset{arrow/.pic={
    \draw[-latex,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);%
}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = {%
            markings,%
            mark =%
                between positions 0 and 1 step 5mm % adjust step size here
                with {%
                     {\pic {arrow};},
                      postaction={decorate}}%
            }%
        ]%
        \path[decorate] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) node (n1)  [pos=0.5, below = 4 pt , draw, text width=3em, minimum height=2em]   {node 1};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```