# How can I create a comma-separated list of characters from a text string?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops, strings, comma-separated-list

How can I split the string `Hello World!` - stored into a macro `\def\mystring{Hello Word!}` - into a comma-separated list of characters (including spaces) which can be used as argument of a `\foreach` loop (`\foreach \char in {\myCSlist}`) in order to loop over each character (as with `\foreach \char in {H,e,l,l,o,\space,W,o,r,l,d,!})`?

### EDIT 1 (Mar 21): Why I want that?

At first, I didn't explain why I want the solution generates a comma-separated list of characters (e.g. `\myCSlist`) which can be used as argument of a `\foreach`. It's because I want to create a Tikz `\node` for each character using a `pic`. Something like this (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637601/262081)):

```
\newcommand{\hsp}{.5}
\tikzset{symbols/.pic={%
    \foreach \s[count=\n from 0] in {\myCSlist}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{360*rnd}%
    \node[rotate=\myangle] at (\hsp*\n,0){\s};%
}}}%
```

### First attempt

I tried with the `\markletters` macro of [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359204/262081) (using xparse and expl3) but the results seems to be not suitable for looping with `foreach`.

I changed the result print - of the `\markletters` macro - from `(##1)` to `##1,`, in order to obtain a comma-separated list, but this also results in a unwanted comma `,` at the end of the comma-separated list.

Here a M(Non)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% For the \foreach loop
\usepackage{xparse}

% egreg's \markletters macro : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359204/262081
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\markletters}{om}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \kessels_markletters:nn { #2 } { \tl_use:N \l_kessels_marked_letters_tl }
   }
   {
    \kessels_markletters:nn { #2 } { \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_kessels_marked_letters_tl }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_kessels_unmarked_letters_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kessels_marked_letters_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kessels_markletters:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_kessels_unmarked_letters_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_kessels_unmarked_letters_tl { ~ } { \textvisiblespace }
  \tl_clear:N \l_kessels_marked_letters_tl
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_kessels_unmarked_letters_tl
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_kessels_marked_letters_tl { ##1, }
   }
  #2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\mystring{Hello World!}

\begin{document}
\markletters[\foo]{\mystring}%
\foreach \char in {\foo}{%
    <\char>%
}%
\end{document}
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

But I would prefer this result (note the presence of the space between 'Hello' and 'World'):

[image]

Comment: Are you interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Please advise.

Comment: If you use lualatex, then you can use a normal looking programming language `lua` to do this, instead of all this weird `\tl_new:N #` unreadable  stuff :)

Comment: @Mico Yes I am (I don't understand Lua or expl3 anyway :)! I don't really care what language is used...

Comment: @SylvainRigal - I've posted a LuaLaTeX-based answer that can handle utf8-encoded, as opposed to "just" ascii-encoded, characters in the input string.

Comment: But it’s *"[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)"* (not *"Hello World!"*).

Comment: See also xstring package and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1|39.3919

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using the package `xstring`. The code also uses `\foreach`, which is part of `tikz` but can be loaded with `pgffor` if your document doesn't use tikz.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % to use accented characters and others
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor} % in case you're not using tikz

\newcommand{\markletters}[1]{\StrLen{#1}[\strlen]\foreach \chr in {1,...,\strlen}{$<$\StrChar{#1}{\chr}$>$}}

\begin{document}

\markletters{Hello World!}

\markletters{äöü ÄÖÜ // ß}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. How might your code need to be adapted to handle utf8-encoded, as opposed to ascii-encoded, characters?

Comment: @Mico: Good thought. This code works fine if you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It's fully utf8-code aware, i.e., the input string may contain utf8-encoded, as opposed to just ascii-encoded, characters.

The code consists of a Lua function named `DoString` and a LaTeX utility macros called `\DoString`, which takes 1 argument -- a character string -- and passes it to the Lua function for further processing.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
function DoString ( s )
  for i = 1,string.utflength(s) do 
    tex.sprint ( '<' .. unicode.utf8.sub ( s , i , i ) .. '>' )
  end
end
}
%% Define a LaTeX utility macro:
\newcommand\DoString[1]{\directlua{DoString("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\DoString{Hello World!}

\DoString{äöü ÄÖÜ // ß}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: To create tikz nodes along the lines suggested in the comment, I suggest you (a) load the `luacode` package (for the `\luaexec` macro) and (b) change the `\directlua{...}` chunk to

```
\luaexec{
function DoString ( s )
  for i = 1,string.utflength(s) do 
    tex.sprint ( '\\node{' .. unicode.utf8.sub ( s , i , i ) .. '};' )
  end
end
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a Tikz `node` for each character? I tried something like this: `tex.sprint ( '\node{' .. unicode.utf8.sub ( s , i , i ) .. '};' )` but I got an error. At the end I would like to use these nodes in a Tikz `pic` as shown in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637465/262081) (see EDIT 4 and look for the `\foreach \s[count=\n] in {a,b,c,f}` part. I want to replace the `{a,b,c,f}` list with the output of your macro).

Comment: @SylvainRigal - Pleas see the addendum I just posted. A major caveat: While the code suggested in the addendum should compile, I have no idea if it'll actually work for you as I don't use TikZ myself.

Comment: The addendum works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The font seems to be different from the default Latex font. Is there a way to set the default Latex font with your code?

Comment: @SylvainRigal - The instruction `\ttfamily` invokes the default monospaced (aka tele-type) font. If you want the default serif font (called Computer/Latin Modern), simply omit `\ttfamily`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why put `\ttfamily`? Is this a Lua coder reflex ;)?

Comment: @SylvainRigal - A monospaced font assigns the same width to all characters, including the space character. I thought that using a monospaced font would make reading the output of `\DoString` marginally easier. It would appear, though, that this attempt was a complete dud, and quite likely even counterproductive. Oh well.

Comment: I learn some things, so it wasn't improductive for me. Thank you very much for your reactivity and support!

Answer (score 9):

Here I use a token cycle.  No mention was made of macros or groups appearing in the input (only characters and spaces), and so those should be excluded from the input, unless the OP advises on how they should be handled.

If one wishes to then use this list in a for-like loop, one can use `\foreachitem` from the `listofitems` package, after reading the comma-separated `\mystring` into a list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,listofitems}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{,#1}}
\Spacedirective{\addcytoks{,#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\markletters[1]{%
  \tokcyclexpress{#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mystring
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  {\expandafter\@gobble\the\cytoks}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\markletters{Hello World!}

(\detokenize\expandafter{\mystring})

\readlist\mylist\mystring

\foreachitem\z\in\mylist{$<$\z$>$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the whole process could be done more simply inside the token cycle, such that `listofitems` would not even be needed.  And, much to my surprise, if I compile under lualatex, it properly handles UTF-8 input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\markletters[1]{%
  \tokencycle{$<$##1$>$}{}{}{$<$##1$>$}#1\endtokencycle%
}
\begin{document}
\markletters{Hello World! äöü ÄÖÜ // ß}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Based on OP comments, here is a version (based on the first approach) that handles macros and groups.  However, macros requiring arguments would have to be handled carefully, since the comma is being inserted after each token/group.

In this implementation, group content is merely echoed as a single entity.  If one wanted group content, subdivided by token, `tokcycle` can do that, but it is not done in this implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle,listofitems}
\makeatletter
\stripgroupingtrue
\newcommand\markletters[1]{%
  \tokcycle{\addcytoks{,##1}}{\addcytoks{,}\groupedcytoks{##1}}%
    {\addcytoks{,##1}}{\addcytoks{,##1}}{#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mystring
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  {\expandafter\@gobble\the\cytoks}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\markletters{Hello World! \today{} is a great day}

(\detokenize\expandafter{\mystring})

\readlist\mylist\mystring

\foreachitem\z\in\mylist{$<$\z$>$}

\mylist[7] is the 7th token

\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\mylist[14]}
 is the 14th token
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. How might your code need to be adapted to handle utf8-encoded, as opposed to ascii-encoded, characters?

Comment: @Mico I think I was mistaken.  If I compile under lualatex and use `\markletters{Hello World! äöü ÄÖÜ // ß}`, I get the correct result.  Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I completely forgot about macros... That would be very nice indeed. Should I post another question because this one is already quite loaded? Could you advise me because I have never had to make such a big modification to a question that already had so many acceptable answers...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Is there a way to acces to the character position number in your macro in order to achieve something like this (where `\charPos` is an integer corresponding to the character position started from 0): `\tokencycle{\node at (\charPos,0) {##1};}{}{}{\nodeat (\charPos,0) {##1};}#1\endtokencycle%`? At the end I would like to use these nodes in a Tikz `pic` as shown in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637465/262081) (see EDIT 4 and look for the `\foreach \s[count=\n] in {a,b,c,f}` part. I want to replace the `{a,b,c,f}` list with the output of your macro).

Comment: @SylvainRigal As to the situation with macros, the issue (as always) is that some macros take arguments.  And arguments typically are provided in groups (curly braces).  There is no way to determine on the fly how many arguments a macro takes.  Thus, I could save and isolate the macro (sans arguments), but unless you merely regurgitated the input stream without modification, adding commas for example, would break the ability for any execution of the macro.

Comment: @SylvainRigal As to the issue of character position, the first approach with `listofitems` already gives you this feature.  For example,if you add, to the end of my code, `\mylist[7]`, you will get the 7th token in the list, which is `W`.

Comment: @SylvainRigal Please see the **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer.  Perhaps this gives you more of what you seek.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes About character position number. Yes indeed I can acces to the character position with the `\zcnt` macro provided by `listofitems` package. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your first solution using `listofitems` seems to doesn't work if the string `Hello World!` is stored into a macro: `\def\myFirststring{Hello World!} \markletters{\myFirststring}` (see my question EDIT 3). Is there a way to make it works?

Comment: @SylvainRigal In that case, one needs to expand the macro first, as in `\def\z{Hello World!}\expandafter\markletters\expandafter{\z}`.  Alternately, one could build the expansion into the definition of `\markletters`, with `\newcommand\markletters[1]{\expandafter\tokcyclexpress\expandafter{#1}\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mystring
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
{\expandafter\@gobble\the\cytoks}}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It works fine with your first solution using `listofitems` but I can't make it works with the version which handles macros **AND** the one using only `tokecycle`. Thank you very much for your reactivity and support!

Comment: @SylvainRigal By "handles macros", are you asking about where the string is included in a macro `\def\z{Hello World!}` or are you asking about where the input stream contains a macro `\markletters{This is \today}`?  I would note that the use of `listofitems` facilitates the use of array lists, allowing use of, for example, `\mylist[7]`.  While `tokcycle` could be programmed to produce an array, as well, it would remain simpler to use `listofitems` to index the tokens, recallable by their place in the string.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry, I wasn't clear... You have proposed 3 solutions, 2 using `listofitems` and one using only `tokcycle`. Among the 2 solutions with `listofitems`, one of them works if input stream contains a macro (`\markletters{This is \today}`). **I would like to be able to use a string which is included in a macro (`\def\z{Hello World!}`) as input with all your 3 solutions**. You gave me a way to do it with the first solution using `listofitems` (the one which don't works if input stream contains a macro) but I'm not able to aplly it to the other 2 solutions...

Comment: @SylvainRigal In the 2nd example, `\newcommand\markletters[1]{\tokencycle{$<$##1$>$}{}{$<$##1$>$}{$<$##1$>$}#1\endtokencycle}` will handle macros that don't require arguments.  It will ignore anything in a group `{ }`.

Comment: @SylvainRigal `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\markletters[1]{%
  \tokencycle{\addcytoks{$<$##1$>$}}{\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}{\addcytoks{$<$##1$>$}}#1\endtokencycle%
}
\begin{document}
\markletters{Hello World \today! äö\rule{1ex}{1ex}ü ÄÖÜ // ß}
\end{document}` will handle both macros and groups **UNMODIFIED**, that is, they will not add `< >` around them.  Further, macro arguments must be placed in groups, or the argument will get messed up with additions of `< >`.  See https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle for docs and examples.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a `\stringforeach` command, with the same syntax as `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stringforeach}{}
\def\stringforeach#1#2in{%
  \def\@foreachvariable{#1}%
  \def\@foreachoptions{#2}%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\@foreachexplicit}{\@foreachimplicit}%
}
\def\@foreachexplicit#1{\@stringforeachdo{#1}}
\def\@foreachimplicit#1{\expandafter\@stringforeachdo\expandafter{#1}}
\def\@stringforeachdo#1{%
  \@transformstringintoclist{#1}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{%
    \endgroup
    \noexpand\foreach
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\@foreachvariable}%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\@foreachoptions}%
    in
    \noexpand\@transformedstring
  }\x
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:cpn {@transformstringintoclist} #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \space }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_set:cx { @transformedstring } { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\mystring{Hello World!}

\begin{document}

\stringforeach \char in \mystring {<\char>}

\stringforeach \char in {Hello World!} {<\char>}

\stringforeach \char [count=\x] in \mystring {<\x=\char>}

\stringforeach \char [count=\x] in {Hello World!} {<\x=\char>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need all the `\foreach` features, it's simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\processtokenlist}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% we have a macro
    \sylvain_processtl:Vn #2 { #3 }
   }
   {% we have an explicit token list
    \sylvain_processtl:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__sylvain_processtl_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sylvain_processtl:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__sylvain_processtl_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__sylvain_processtl_tl { ~ } { \c_space_tl }
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__sylvain_processtl_item:n { #2 }
  \tl_map_function:NN \l__sylvain_processtl_tl \__sylvain_processtl_item:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sylvain_processtl:nn { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\mystring{Hello World!}

\begin{document}

\processtokenlist*{\mystring}{<#1>}

\processtokenlist{Hello World!}{<#1>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solutions seem to not well handle UTF-8 encoding (ß character seems to be not well printed). It was not requested in my original question but pointed out by @Mico in comment.

Comment: @SylvainRigal No, currently that's not supported.

Comment: @SylvainRigal - The code shown in this answer can handle utf8-encoded characters just fine as long as the document is compiled under LuaLaTeX. (No need to load the `fontenc` package under LuaLaTeX, though.)

Comment: I first tried with `fontenc` AND LuaLaTeX engine but the "ß" was printed as "SS". Indeed, without `fontenc` it's OK (if compiled under LuaLaTeX). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because we cannot absorb single space by unseparated macro parameter, we must pre-process the given macro by `\replspaces` macro first. Then you can use `\insertcommas` which inserts commas between token but not after the last one. Or `\insertangles` which replaces each `token` by `<token>`.

```
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\replspaces#1{\edef#1{\expandafter\replspacesA#1 \end}}
\def\replspacesA #1 #2{#1\ifx\end#2\else { }\afterfi{\replspacesA#2}\fi}
\def\insertcommas#1{\edef#1{\expandafter\insertcommasA#1\end}}
\def\insertcommasA#1#2{#1\ifx\end#2\else,\afterfi{\insertcommasA{#2}}\fi}
\def\insertangles#1{\edef#1{\expandafter\insertanglesA#1\end}}
\def\insertanglesA#1{\ifx\end#1\else<#1>\expandafter\insertanglesA\fi}

% test:

\def\mystring{Hello World!}

\replspaces\mystring
\insertcommas\mystring
\meaning\mystring  % macro:-> H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d,!

\def\mystring{Hello World!}

\replspaces\mystring
\insertangles\mystring
\meaning\mystring  % macro:-> <H><e><l><l><o>< ><W><o><r><l><d><!>

\bye
```

**Edit** Your first ask was: how to create a macro `H,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,d,!` from the macro `Hello World!`. I answered correctly.

Now, your second ask is: how to use such macro in `\foreach` from Tikz. I don't know how to set effectively the expanded parameter to a somewhat impractical `\foreach` from Tikz (you can use `\expanded{\unexpanded {\foreach ...}{\mystring}}` but it seems horrible). It should be better not to use `\foreach` from Tikz at all and define your own `\myforeach`:

```
\def\replspaces#1{\edef#1{\expandafter\replspacesA#1 \end}}
\def\replspacesA #1 #2{#1\ifx\end#2\else { }\afterfi{\replspacesA#2}\fi}
\def\myforeach#1{\expandafter\myforeachA#1\end}
\def\myforeachA#1{\ifx\end#1\else\body{#1}\expandafter\myforeachA\fi}

\def\body#1{<#1>}
\def\mystring{Hello World!}

\replspaces\mystring 
\myforeach\mystring % prints: <H><e><l><l><o>< ><W><o><r><l><d><!>

\bye
```

Comment: If I do something like this `\replspaces\mystring \insertcommas\mystring \foreach \char in {\mystring}{<\char>}`, it doesn't loop over each character in the string, I just get this: `<H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d,!>`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My first ask was: How to create a macro `H,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,d,!` from the macro `Hello World!` which can be used as an `\foreach` argument? I'm sincerely sorry if it was not clear. I'm sure there are many other way to do it but the  `\foreach`  syntax is easy to use for me and I can acces easily to the loop integer or start it from 0. Anyway, your solution works fine thank you.

Comment: @SylvainRigal The problem is that the parameter for Tikz's `\foreach` must be expanded before the `\foreach` is processed. But you cannot use single `\expandafter` because the parameter is due to the inappropriately `\foreach` syntax positioned at the very back. I don't want to study the 1400 pages manual of Tikz in order to know, how to do it using Tikz concept. It is more simple for me to write my own `\foreach` macro. I hoped that you know how to expand the parameter for `\foreach` from Tikz if you want to use it and that this is not the main problem asked here.

Comment: You're right is not the main problem here... But I disturb you again because I tried to used your `myforeach` with this: `\newcounter{cnt}\setcounter{cnt}{-1}\def\body#1{\stepcounter{cnt}\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{360*rnd}\pgfmathsetmacro{\mystep}{\thecnt}\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{360*rnd}\node[rotate=\myangle] at (\hsp*\mystep,0){#1};}%` but I got the following error: `! Undefined control sequence. \replspacesA ...->#1\ifx \end #2\else { }\afterfi{\replspacesA #2}\fi`.

Comment: Undefined control sequence `\afterfi`? Maybe there is not copied the definition of `\afterfi` from the firs line of my first example. Ii is my mistake that I didn't copied it from my first example to the second.

Comment: I'm so silly, I didn't seen the `\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}` in your first exemple sorry. So your foreach works like a charm to generate my Tikz `pic`, I will update my question with this result... Thans for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using PGF/TikZ you might as well use the `parser` module that comes with it.

We'll define a parser `char parser` that does something (`/char parser/do`) with each letter, for this we need three actions:

1. the one for the space (it's special),
2. the one for every other character and
3. for the end of the parsing.

I'm using a `@`-protected macro `\charparser@stop` to end the parsing since any other letter (like `;`) could show up in the text that shall be parsed.

The action for every other character is done by defining an action for an unknown letter – unknown except for the space or for the ending. The parser would actually raise an error in that case but we can set `char parser/silent=true`.

And then it's just a question about what you want to do with every letter.

We can place a node for it:

```
\tikz[
  /char parser/do/.code={\node[rotate=360*rnd] at (\charparsercount,0) {#1};},
  /char parser/parse={Hello World! äöüßÄÖÜ}
]{}
```

Yes, the parser increments a macro (not a counter) `\charparsercount`. The key `do` will be used with the found character.

We can also make a comma-separated list and use it with `\foreach`:

```
\tikz[
  /char parser/list=\myList,
  /char parser/parse={Hello World! äöüßÄÖÜ}%
]
\foreach \s[count=\n from 0] in \myList
  \node[rotate=360*rnd] at (\n,0) {\s};
```

If you have the to-be-parsed text in a macro just use `/.expand once`:

```
\newcommand*\myText{Hello World! äöüßÄÖ}
/char parser/parse/.expand once=\myText
```

### Code

```
% use lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand*\charparserset{\pgfqkeys{/char parser}}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\pgfparserdefunknown{char parser}{initial}{%
  \pgfkeysalso{/char parser/do/.expand once=\pgfparserletter,/char parser/next}}
\pgfparserdef{char parser}{initial}{blank space}{%
  \pgfkeysalso{/char parser/do=\space,/char parser/next}}
\pgfparserset{char parser/silent=true}
\makeatletter
\pgfparserdef{char parser}{initial}\charparser@stop{%
  \pgfkeysalso{/char parser/final/.try}\pgfparserswitch{final}}
\charparserset{parse/.code={%
    \charparserset{init}%
    \pgfparserparse{char parser}#1\charparser@stop}}
\makeatother
\charparserset{
  init/.code=\def\charparsercount{0},
  next/.code=\edef\charparsercount{\the\numexpr\charparsercount+1\relax},
  list/.style={
    /char parser/final/.append code=\pgfkeysgetvalue{/char parser/@list}#1,
    /char parser/@list/.initial=,
    /char parser/do/.style={
      /char parser/@list/.append={##1},
      /char parser/do/.style={
        /char parser/@list/.append={,####1}}}},
  do/.code={#1}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  x=5mm,
  /char parser/do/.code={\node[rotate=360*rnd] at (\charparsercount,0) {#1};},
  /char parser/parse={Hello World! äöüßÄÖÜ}
]{}
\tikz[
  x=5mm,
  /char parser/list=\myList,
  /char parser/parse={Hello World! äöüßÄÖÜ}%
]
\foreach \s[count=\n from 0] in \myList
  \node[rotate=360*rnd] at (\n,0) {\s};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: And here's the [same answer without `pgfparser`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tex.sx/blob/master/637833.tex) but with only keys and space replacement.